# Creating array that stores button click locations

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a 3 x 3 grid of buttons (created in an HTML table), how might I go about storing in a multidimensional array the coordinates of the button that was pressed. For instance, I have an array:

```
var anArrayOfButtonClicks = anArray(3,3);
function anArray(row, col){
  a = [];
  for(var i=0; i < row; i++){
      a[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j < col; j++){
        a[i][j] = null;
    }
  }return a;
}
```

When I click on the upper-left hand button in the grid, it would store that location [0][0] at that element in the array. How would I go about doing this in JavaScript/jQuery?

HTML table: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/ezLLk6qa/2/

Comment: How are the buttons created? Using loops?

Comment: For this example, the buttons are created in a normal HTML table.

Comment: I would create one event handler and bind it to all of the buttons, then set your array element according to the ID or other identifier of the button that calls the event.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I've added here: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/ezLLk6qa/2/

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wk0qqnrj/)

Comment: That's good but it doesn't seem to solve the issue of storing the locations into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented simply based on id's of buttons. Id are defined as grid index separated by underscore.

You can check the jsFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ajaykedare/ezLLk6qa/14/

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><button id="0_0" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="0_1" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="0_2" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button id="1_0" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="1_1" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="1_2" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button id="2_0" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="2_1" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
<td><button id="2_2" onclick="storeAtIndex(id);"></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var anArrayOfButtonClicks = Create2DArray(3);

storeAtIndex = function (id) {
var splitarray = id.split("_")
var i = splitarray[0]
var j = splitarray[1]
//Store value at that location
anArrayOfButtonClicks[i][j] = "Some value at index: "+i+j
//Check if value is stored successfully
alert("Does ele stored ?"+anArrayOfButtonClicks[i][j])
}

function Create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> it would store that location [0][0] at that element in the array

When you say *it would store that location[0][0] at that element in the array*...I'm assuming you mean the specific x,y coordinates of the mouse click.

In which case, if you put an `onclick=` method on each of your buttons passing their "grid_based" coordinates like:

```
<button id="grid_button_0_0" onclick="handleGridButtonClick(event, 0, 0)" >
</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function handleGridButtonClick(evt, grid_x, grid_y){
  anArrayOfButtonClicks[grid_x][grid_y] = {
    screen_x: evt.screenX,
    screen_y: evt.screenY
  };
}
</script>
```

You'll be able to do what you're talking about.

If you meant to store some other value - or just the fact that the grid-addressed button had been clicked, you can simplify this by removing the event parameter and set `anArrayOfButtonClicks[grid_x][grid_y]` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.map()`, .each()`,`.closest()`,`index()`; using`id`of`button` as property of object with array

```js
var grid = $("table tr").map(function() {
  var obj = {}; 
  $("button", this).each(function(i, el) {
    obj[el.id] = [];
  });
  return obj
}).get();

$("tr button[id]").click(function(e) {
   var curr = $(this).closest("tr").index();
   grid[curr][this.id]
   .push([e.clientX, e.clientY]);
   alert(JSON.stringify(grid[curr][this.id]));
   console.log(grid);
})
```

```css
button{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><button id="a0"></button></td>
<td><button id="a1"></button></td>
<td><button id="a2"></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button id="b0"></button></td>
<td><button id="b1"></button></td>
<td><button id="b2"></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button id="c0"></button></td>
<td><button id="c1"></button></td>
<td><button id="c2"></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ezLLk6qa/13/